# How to Merge without overwriting columns not in parameter (JPA)?

Tags: java, jpa

I have a table called

```
Customer

Custid:
Custusername:
Custaddr:
CustDateOfBirth:
```

Now, i have an update parameter that wants the user to update only "Custusername,Custaddr" won't make sense to update Dateofbirth (So after registration, it's permanent).

So i do something like this :

```
Customer.setCustid(Custid);
Customer.setCustaddr(Custaddr);
Customer.setusername(Custid);
```

Then i use entity manager :

```
em.merge(Customer);
```

So what happens is, the details get updated but ! The **Dateofbirth** is now null in the database regardless of the fact that i didnt set any parameter to it.

I did this before, but the method returns true without any changes made :

```
//The Set statements are above
emm.getTransaction().begin(); 
try {  
    emm.merge(emm.find(Customer.class, Custid);
    emm.getTransaction().commit();
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    emm.getTransaction().rollback();
    System.out.println( e);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you creating your customer?You need to find customer by id, then change it and merge it back to db

```
 Customer c = em.find(Customer.class, id);
 c.setCustaddr(custaddr);
 em.merget(c);
```

Now you are creating completely new entity and merging it with the old one, it's just logical that all fields are getting overriden by the this new entity in the DB.

Comment: I tried that earlier but it didnt do any changes. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Eh, in the code in your question you don't edit anything, so what did you expect to change in the DB?

Comment: In the code i wrote that `//The Set statements are above` meaning i excluded them. So there, i have codes like .. `Customer.setCustusername(username)`

Answer (score 0):

Look into the dynamic-update property.

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate=true)
```

dynamic-update (optional - defaults to false): specifies that UPDATE SQL should be generated at runtime and can contain only those columns whose values have changed.

Comment: @A Paul, i am using only JPA and not hibernate. Can this still be done ?

Comment: yah. It can be done. You need hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.jar. This is part of JPA. One suggestiong, just google it with JPA you will get examples.